# (Py)Spark wirting to postgres using JDBC fails with NullPointerException

Tags: python, postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to save the results from a PySpark calculation to a PostgreSQL database.

To save the dataframe I use the following code:

```py
url = "jdbc:porstgresql://{0}:{1}/{2}".format(
            postgres_config["url"],
            postgres_config["port"],
            postgres_config["database"]
        )

        table = "{0}.{1}".format(
            postgres_config["schema"],
            postgres_config["table_name"]
        )

        properties = {
            "user": "user",
            "password": "****",
            "driver": "org.postgresql.Driver"
        }

        writer = DataFrameWriter(df_result)
        writer.jdbc(
            url=url,
            table=table,
            mode=mode,
            properties=properties
        )
```

But this results in the following exception, which is quite unclear.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o412.jdbc.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:46)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:499)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm using `jdbc-postgres-9.4.jar` for the driver and PostgreSQL 11.7.
Did any of you experience this or something similar before? Or has any hint how to continue?
It seems to me as if the table can not be created, but I can't understand why. User is admin-user.

**EDIT 1:**

Counted rows of my result and it turned out it has 0 rows. Could this be an issue here?
Tried with a filled dataframe and results in the same error

**EDIT 2:**

When using Spark2 it leeds to the upper stacktrace. Switching back to Spark1 leads to the following one:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o108.jdbc.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.jdbc(DataFrameWriter.scala:308)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It's the lower part of the upper stack trace. Could be a hint that error is within Spark?

Comment: The 9.4 driver is pretty old and might not necessarily work with PostgreSQL 11 (although the stacktrace suggests the problem is within Spark itself). Consider updating to a more recent version. The latest version of the PostgreSQL JDBC driver is 42.2.18.

Comment: I used the latest version of the driver but still ran into the same issue. I also checked if my result is null and counted rows: Turned out it has zero. Could this be an issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Quite hard to admit, error was a typo... Connection string was wrong.

`NullPointerException` is thrown because of bug in Spark version < 2.4.
For more information see [this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-26383).